# Restrict Specific Nodes to Roles

Tags: nodes, users

I been using Drupal for a while, but I am completely in the dark when it comes to Roles, permissions, etc.

What I want to do is have all my content types, but I want to restrict certain nodes for certain roles. Does anybody know any modules or if the core can do this? The reason why I am doing this is to share with a specific group of people on my site.

Thanks!

Comment: Specific nodes or Specific content types ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to achieve this.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.

Comment: Or http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole